# Mail feature in Unix sends a file named 'eml' with no file extension instead of the expected zip file in another server

Tags: shell, unix, mailx

I am not sure if this could be remedied by Programming means but I had a MailX shell script that was working properly in the test server. But when I run the script in the production server, the recipient only receives a file named 'eml' that can't be even opened. I was informed by the system administrator that the configurations of both servers are the same and I should be adjusting my code.
But I used the exact same shell script and it works in the test server.

```
cd /home/guava/autoemail

datediff=1
datetoday=$(date +%Y%m%d)
foldername=$(date --date="${datetoday} -${datediff} day" +%Y%m%d)

mv DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP.xls DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.xls
zip -P $foldername DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.zip DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.xls
cat /home/guava/autoemail/email_body.txt | mailx -s "AML_20M_DAILY_TRANSACTION_REPORT_GUAVA_$foldername" -a /home/guava/autoemail/DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.zip ben@onionwank.com
rm DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.xls
rm DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_$foldername.zip
```

what it does:
-declares the date yesterday
-renames an excel file with the yesterday's date
-zip the excel file with a password
-email it to the user
-delete the used files.

I just want to ask if there is anything I can improve with my code so I can use it in the production server. Why does the server send an 'eml' file instead of the attachment I defined?

It is possible that this is a server issue but the system admins don't seem to know what to do.

Comment: Why are none of the variables quoted?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Why should I quote them?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting